# Nexus get dependencies REST or create plugin

Tags: rest, plugins, nexus, sonatype

Pro edition of Nexus shows the dependencies for an artifact...

Want to do the same in the Community edition.  Doesn't look like the standard REST API:

```
 https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/data_ns0.html
```

supplies a service for dependencies.  Have googled for examples on creating plugins (not too charged about the Nexus documentation on plugins right now) and toying with the idea of creating a plugin (a REST based) that pulls out dependencies per artifact.  Ideas?

Comment: Assume the for Nexus (in the Pro edition) to list out dependencies the sourced information is housed in the associated POM?  So a hacky solution would be just to navigate to the POM and pull it down.

Answer (score 3):

From what I know Nexus basically downloads the pom.xml of the project you are interested and runs the list or tree goals of the maven dependency plugin and then just displays the results nicely.

You could of course do the same in your own custom plugin. You can also use the Aether API and  others directly to do the dependency resolution in your plugin and not call the plugin externally and then show the results.. in fact Nexus might just be doing that.

Realistically writing this yourself that sounds like reinventing the wheel and I would just get a Pro license. Beyond that minimal feature, there are a LOT of other benefits to pro. Just give it a try.

Comment: Lookat Aether (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether) which looks general purpose.  Going to look into how to write a plugin (REST) since some sort of integration directly in the Nexus server is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this "headless" plugin (plugin that offers services to other plugins, not having any functionality or UI on its own):
https://github.com/sonatype/nexus/tree/master/nexus/nexus-core-plugins/nexus-maven-bridge-plugin

Nexus uses pure Aether, not (whole) Maven - as Manfred says - to calculate the tree of dependencies.... again, just take a peek at that plugin above, it's there ;)

Comment: Nice tip!  Exploded the dependency report plugin and yes the Aether stuff is used with Plexus (as something new to me).  Looks fairly easy to understand the use of Plexus and pushing in Extjs code (that I have done before).  Aether looks like it rolls beans that map directly to a POM and uses a HTTP client to do a multipart form post when updating to a repo.  Haven't found the exactly how the POM is saved but my guess is directly in the file system and cached and dependencies are sourced from POM files.

Comment: I did say it was just a guess that it is using Maven... ;-)

Comment: Will post back what I find but at a glance there are bunch of JAXB like (XSteam) beans hanging around that are likely rolled from a cache from a file that is likely a POM.  ;-)